# Serve vue-cli project with valet

Tags: macos, vue-cli-3, valet

I'm trying to serve a local website using `valet`, but unsuccessfully.

```
vue create my-project
cd my-project
```

If I serve the project with:

```
npm run serve
```

I get the default page with **Vue** logo.

But if I serve the project using `valet` (with `park` or `link` option), I get a blank page.

How can I serve `vue-cli` project using `valet` ?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't work with `vue-cli-service serve`, I have found a workaround that works with build.

You can serve static sites using [this driver](https://github.com/samturrell/static-valet-driver).

After installing the driver:

```sh
$ cd my-vue-project
$ yarn build

$ cd dist
$ touch static
$ valet link acme
$ mkdir public
$ mv ./* public
```

You can then view the built Vue site at http://acme.test.  The downside is needing to rebuild everytime you make a change, but it works for testing when needed.